# what are the solutions for efficient feature selection in a very large feature space?

Tags: feature-selection

I have a classification dataset (50k observations and 10 features) on which I can't get a good result..

I want to try increasing the number of features..

I plan to automatically generate many feature options from whatever seems reasonable to me for my dataset.
When I roughly calculated the number of possible signs, they turned out to be about 100 million or more ...

Naturally, such a large number of features cannot be processed at once, and 99.9% of the features will turn out to be unimportant.

My plan is this:

1. create a date set of 100/1000 features
2. train the model
3. choose features that are important from the point of view of the classification algorithm
4. save important features
5. transition to point "1" but with new features

My question is this:

1. What are the effective strategies for selecting features if there are potentially millions or more features.
2. Is my plan correct, or am I missing something?

**upd_for_Dave===========================**

Here is a little `R` code how I plan to generate features with a very simple and "small" grammar

```
library("gramEvol")
grammarDef <- CreateGrammar(list(
  expr  = grule(op(expr, expr), func(expr), var),
  func  = grule(sin, cos, log, sqrt),
  op    = grule("+","-","*","/"), 
  var   = grule(var, var^n),
  n     = gvrule(1:4),
  var   = grule(x1,x2)))
```

Here are the potential `features` that this grammar generates

```
gramEvol::GrammarRandomExpression(grammarDef,numExpr = 10)

[[1]]
expression(x2)

[[2]]
expression(x2)

[[3]]
expression(cos(sqrt(x1 + sqrt(x1)) + sqrt(x1)))

[[4]]
expression(cos(sqrt(sin(sqrt(cos(log(sin(log(x2))) * cos(sqrt(cos(x1)))))))) - cos(x2 * x2))

[[5]]
expression(log(x1))

[[6]]
expression(x2)

[[7]]
expression(sqrt(cos(x2 * (x1 - sqrt(log((sqrt(x1) + x1)/x2/x2)/(sin(x1) * x2))))))

[[8]]
expression(cos(x1))

[[9]]
expression(x2)

[[10]]
expression(cos(x2))
```

So many unique combinations

```
summary(grammarDef)
No. of Unique Expressions:   3.993138e+15
```

And this is only with this simple grammar, but you can do not only mathematical expressions, but code, text .. anything ..
But I think this is all beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: How are you generating those millions of features?

Comment: As a "feature generator" I'm going to use a symbolic regression/genetic progmaming library..
With this algorithm, I can essentially generate code that in turn generates features of any type

Comment: @Dave see my update

Comment: What do you do once you get these features? For instance, do you run a linear regression on them?

Comment: I was thinking of using XGboost to immediately extract important features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is good enough, but features based on 1 feature can also be used.
I use Weight of Evidence (WOE) and Information Value (IV) when there are many features. I would bin the variable, calculate the IV, throw out the obviously bad ones (iv < 0.03 for example) and make a feature / iv table. I also have some heuristic rule: I will add features to the model as long as they add at least 0.01 roc_auc_score. If the 1-variable model has abs(roc_auc_score) < 0.501 then I remove it from the sample.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I have a few questions if you don't mind.
1) Did I understand correctly? I need to train a single feature model with good WOE/IV and if it gives a positive ROC AUC then add it to the overall big model?
2) The correlation of signs is not taken into account in any way, right?
3) I heard that WOE is suitable for logistic regression and cannot catch non-linear relationships, is that so?

Comment: Not quite. I propose 2 one-dimensional criteria to remove obviously weak functions. 1 small iv<0.02, 2 small quality metric (roc_auc for example). Yes, indeed, iv is suitable for linear models, but my heuristic is that too small iv will not give an increase in the quality metric in a nonlinear model.

Comment: Since the number of features is too large to calculate "honestly" the importance of certain features, I suggest throwing out the features according to the principle: if the feature itself does not display the target variable in any way, then it is not needed in the final model. Since you seem to generate all sorts of combinations anyway, then you don't need weak features that, in certain rare cases, can give an increase in quality metrics in non-linear combinations. After all, this information will be taken into account in another good sign.